# How to embed work items from Azure DevOps

Tags: embedded, azure-devops

is there a way to embed work items from Azure DevOps into Sharepoint? My team is writing up a release plan and we would like to reference a few work items (possibly with statuses) on the page so we can have overall picture of where we're at.

I know this is really simple to do in Atlassian's Confluence & Jira so sounds like a no brainer but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB integration between SPO and Azure DevOps. At least, you will not see the same type of integration that Confluence and Jira has to offer.

In a way, Azure DevOps has both features of Jira and Source control baked in. However, it lacks the "Confluence" part. However, Microsoft has MS Teams, which brings all of these tools together. For example, there is the **Azure DevOps** connector. It allows you to see the ADO boards.

[image]

[image]

[More details here: Microsoft Teams with Azure DevOps Services (Collaborate, Communicate and Celebrate)](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/#azure-devops-kanban-board--dashboards-in-teams)